# Is there an Android reference for common resource identifiers?

Tags: android

Where can one find a list of resource identifiers for common Android elements and their attributes?

For example:

```
getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android")
```

Comment: You always have [android.R](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.html) Which work the same way as R but contains android's constants.

Comment: This question needs more upvotes. It's shame that in a lot of examples, even in the Android docs, we see code snippets like above with hardcoded values like "status_bar_height", but there is no documentation page describing all such constants and we must guess, search or imagine what there might be.

Answer (score 1):

you can identify the commom resouces by using one of these methods.

Using xml for exemple set heigth to statusbar:

```
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

Or by java code:

```
toolbarinfocasa.setMinimumHeight(android.R.attr.actionBarSize);
```